# Nesting Design Pattern given Solidity Limitation

Tags: contract-design, design-patterns, unittesting

### What I have so far

I have a Validator contract that is supposed to insert a key-value pair in the database contingently on a particular invariant being satisfied.

```
contract Validator
{
   DataBase dataBase;
   Aggregator aggregator;

   function Validator(
       DataBase _database,
       Aggregator _aggregator
   )
   {
      database = _database;
      aggregator = _aggregator;
   }

   function insert(uint key, uint value)
   {
     dataBase.insert(key, value);
     assert(aggregator.ComplexFunction() > 0);
   }
}
```

I have a contract Aggregator (with various internal functions used as subroutines) which computes a complex function that necessitates informations from the DataBase and from an ExtraInfoProvider (which is a preexisting contract that I did not write).

```
contract Aggregator
    {
        DataBase database;
        ExtraInfoProvider extraInfoProvider;

        function Aggregator(DataBase _database, ExtraInfoProvider _extrainfoProvider)
        {
           database = _database;
           extraInfoProvider = _extraInfoProvider;
        }

        function ComplexFunction()
        {
          // Compute complex function which involves iterating over
          // all of the key-value pair in the database and consulting 
          // the ExtraInfoProvider

        }
    }
```

Finally I have a DataBase which supports iterating over the keys: note the use of getKeyCount and getKey to get around the impossibility of returning dynamically sized array in Solidity; (experienced solidity programmers are probably very familiar with this)

```
contract DataBase
{
    function getKeyCount() returns (uint keyCount);

    function getKey(uint index) returns (uint key);

    function get(uint key) returns value;

    function insert(key, value)
}
```

The problem with this organization is the complex nesting between the classes, which is reflected by the impossibility of creating clean unit-tests.

I would like to be able to create a MockDataBase and a MockAggregator in order to be able to cleanly UnitTest my Validator class without having to pass an instance of MockDataBase to the MockAggregator

### What I would like to have

In an ideal world where Solidity supports passing  dynamic arrays AND structures between contracts you could do something as follow:

```
struct KeyValuePair
{
    uint key;
    uint value;
}

contract Validator
{
   DataBase dataBase;
   Aggregator aggregator;

   function Validator(
      DataBase _database,
      Aggregator _aggregator
   )
   {
      database = _database;
      aggregator = _aggregator;
   }

   function insert(uint key, uint value)
   {
     dataBase.insert(key, value);

     KeyValuePair[] pairs = database.getAllKeyValuePairs();
     assert(aggregator.ComplexFunction(pairs) > 0);
   }
}
```

This would allow me to cleanly mock the Aggregator and the Database.

How could I achieve this result given the constraint present in Solidity?

(I could collect keys and values and create 2 dynamic arrays in the Validator and pass them to the Aggregator, but I do not like the idea of passing two arrays which are supposed to by in sync).

### This is not entirely about testing

I don't intend to start an argument between Classicists and UnitTester: I perform both UnitTest and organic tests with real objects on my contracts.
This is not entirely about testing: I am concerned about the pattern above as a general code smell.

I don't like the necessity for synchronization between the Aggregator and the Database: for example, if I want to augment my system to allow contracts upgrades, it would be way easier to substitute my Aggregator and my DataBase independently if they did not have mutual dependencies.